# Firebase, environment variables clarification

Tags: firebase, environment-variables

I'm trying to implement the environment variables in my firebase functions

I set my vars as stated in this doc, https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env.

I checked that the operation suceeded running

```
firebase functions:config:get
```

However, I would expect my variables to appear here

[image]

Why this doesn't happen? Those are different types of env vars? Is it possible to check the env vars added through Firebase Cli in the Google Cloud Platform ?

Thanks for any clarification

Comment: Please explain whether you want to set it or get the variables from firebase environment

Comment: My question is wheather the vars set using the Firebase Cli are visible from the Google Cloud Platform

Comment: it's visible but you haven't set the variable i think. You have to set the variable and push the function to check.

Comment: What do you see in the Google Cloud Console that does not correspond to what you expect?

Comment: I'm new with Firebase so I probably misunderstood something. The point is: given I added an environmental variable (following this steps https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) and I'm actually able to retrieve it from my cloud functions (functions.config().someservice.id) I would expect to see it in the Google Cloud Platform (under Cloud Functions -> Variables). This doesn't happen and I'm sure there's a good reason I'm not getting. I just want to understand that. Hope I'm making myself clear. Thanks